# Connect alauda driver to an mtd device

Tags: linux, drivers, flash-memory

I have a USB card reader, an Olympus MAUSB-10.  It provides direct flash access to SmartMedia or xD cards, using the Linux `alauda` driver.  This is different from a typical card reader which just exposes it as a standard USB mass storage device.

There's drivers in the Linux kernel that will do the FTL thing and expose this as a standard block device, but I want direct flash access.  I was wondering if it's possible to use the various utilities of `mtd-tools` to read, write, and erase directly to it.

So the device is recognized by `lsusb`, and drivers `aluada` and `nand_ecc` are loaded.  But `cat /proc/mtd` isn't revealing another MTD device available, and I don't see any additional devices in `/dev`.  How do I create a new mtd device and connect it to the alauda driver?

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the source code of driver in the Linux kernel (`drivers/mtd/nand/alauda.c`), we see that the mtd device should be called "alauda".

For example, in cmx270_nand.c mtd name is cmx270-0. In kernel log information about it, looks like:

```
Creating 1 MTD partitions on "NAND 512MiB 3,3V 8-bit":
0x00000000-0x20000000 : "cmx270-0"
```

Check dmesg (grep alauda, MTD), and if your xD card successfully recognized, finally for accessing MTD device you may try create `/dev/mtdblockX` and `/dev/mtdX` with `mknod`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The xD card is successfully recognized (showed up as /dev/sde).  `mknod /dev/mtd0 c 90 0` doesn't do anything, `mtdinfo` gives me error 19 (no such device).  `/proc/mtd` doesn't reveal any MTD devices.  An `lsmod | grep alauda` reveals that `mtd` and `mtdchar` are both loaded.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. remove (rmmod) the ums-alauda driver
2. after plugging in the device, check if module alauda's probe print is seen via dmesg
3. if device /dev/mtd0 not seen, rmmod alauda, and insmod it again

   - there shouldnt be a need to mknod.
     (try with the 'lid' shut).